# Debugging Mono outside of MonoDevelop

Tags: mono, debugging

I've been writing a console application in C# using MonoDevelop. While I can run the application and pass command line arguments to it, i cannot for the life of me figure out how to debug it and pass in arguments.

I've tried using the command line to launch MDB - [Instructions Here](http://www.mono-project.com/Guide%3aDebugger)

However on Ubuntu 11.10 it cannot locate the Debugger

```
 05:15:53 {master} ~/Projects/SomeProject/bin/Debug$ mdb
No command 'mdb' found, did you mean:
```

So, where is the mono debugger, and how do I debug command line applications built with mono that depend on arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support for the 'hard debugger' is no longer included in the runtime, so the mono-debugger package was removed from Debian & Ubuntu. The interface that monodevelop uses is called the soft debugger, and there is the start of a command-line client for that at https://github.com/alexrp/sdb-cli

Comment: That GitHub link is dead. Maybe moved to [this repo](https://github.com/mono/sdb)?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have installed both the `mono-complete`, `monodevelop`, and
`monodevelop-debugger-gdb` packages. Perhaps you may be missing the `monodevelop-debugger-gdb` package.